# How do I get the output of Erlang's preprocessor?

Tags: erlang, preprocessor

I've got a weird macro that I'm debugging and I can't seem to figure out how to get the output of the preprocessor. I'm looking for the equivalent of GCC's `-save-temps`. I've tried passing `dpp` to `compile:file/2`, but it seems to generate a parse tree, not preprocessed Erlang.

`compile:file("t.erl", 'E').` as mentioned by Anton is great, but doesn't help with macros that cause syntax errors. Lacking a way to debug complicated macros, I'm leaning toward doing my metaprogramming by writing programs that generate code.

Comment: You cannot use the compiler interface directly because, as you point out, it only works for files without parse errors. However, you can call the epp module (Erlang pre-processor) directly and get it to return the tokens returned after macros have been expanded. There is nice function called `epp:scan_erl_form/1` (undocumented but definitely *safe*) which works in much the same way as `epp:parse_erl_form/1` but without parsing. Of course generating code is definitely fun, if you are a lisp programmer try using LFE (Lisp Flavoured Erlang) which makes it easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
   compile:file("t.erl", 'P').
   compile:file("t.erl", 'E').
```

Comment: Those return `error` and don't generate any output (with my faulty macro; `E` does great things if I don't have any errors).

Comment: @nmichaels what to do to see the processor output if things don't compile without errors?